# How to show data in my view from the backend using DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net, html-helper

How to show this data on my view `{ TextCode = "Hello", Description = "Hello, How are you ",Text = "Great" }`

My Code is

`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Texts[].Description);`

I want to show it in this way but how to specify the exact particular `textCode`, I cant just put index in `Texts[]`, because the index might change later on when I add more texts

Comment: Where does `Texts[]` come from? you have no property Texts in your data specified.

Comment: `Texts = new List<Text>(){
....................
}`

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Show us your controller method so we can see, where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use array in this way, you have to iterate:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Texts)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `model.Texts[]`. It's look like you are using `List<Texts>`

Simple you `foreach` loop. Try this

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Texts)
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)
}
```

This loop through each `Texts`.